# Can someone tell why Chem.MolFromSmiles is not converting list of SMILES into mol objects in RDKit?

Tags: python, c++, rdkit, cheminformatics

I have a list of 298 SMILES and I want to turn those 298 into mol objects however rdkit is giving me the above error.

```
TypeError: No registered converter was able to produce a C++  

 rvalue of type std::basic_string<wchar_t, 
  std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > from this 
  Python object of type float
```

This is my code:

```
for mol in str_smiles:
  Chem.MolFromSmiles(mol)
  mol_object_list.append(mol)
```

Can someone tell what's wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code you presented won't work because you need to assign the object to something first. Something like this:

```py
mol_object_list = []
for smi in str_smiles:
    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi)
    mol_object_list.append(mol)
```

Coming back to your error, the error occurs when the SMILES string input is invalid. It's possible some of the SMILES in `str_smiles` list are wrong. Try the following piece of code to figure out which ones:

```
mol_object_list = []
for smi in str_smiles:
    try:  # Try converting the SMILES to mol object
        mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi)
        mol_object_list.append(mol)
    except:  # Print the SMILES if there was an error in converting
        print(smi)
```

The SMILES that are printed are invalid and you have to fix them.

P.S. I'm assuming that `str_smiles` is a python list.